# Calling external function within AngularJS Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looking to run an external JS function which gathers data from a REST endpoint, as such it takes a small amount of time to do so. This data is to be inserted into a graph but the graph is attempting to load before the data is collected.

External JS:

```
function callEndpoint() {
    var sensorID = document.getElementById('sensorList').value;
    $.getJSON('http://193.61.148.125:443/SensorCentral/REST/SensorDataRangeNanos/19455746_3_10?startTs=0&endTs=9000000000000000000',
    function(data) {
        globalData = data;
     });
}
```

My root.js:

```
angular.module('root',['AngularChart'], function( $routeProvider, $locationProvider ){
    $routeProvider.when('/',{
        template: '<chart title="Bedroom Sensors" xData="lineChartXData" yData="lineChartYData" xName="Month" yName="Activations" subtitle="Sensor Usage"></chart>',
        controller:  MainCtrl
        })
})
```

My attempt at using a service:

```
angular.module('root',['AngularChart'], function( $routeProvider, $locationProvider ){
        service('myService', function() {
            this.callAlert = function() {
              callEndpoint();
        }});
    $routeProvider.when('/',{
        template: '<chart title="Bedroom Sensors" xData="lineChartXData" yData="lineChartYData" xName="Month" yName="Activations" subtitle="Sensor Usage"></chart>',
        controller: MainCtrl
        })
})
```

EDIT:

I'm accessing `globalData` though a function call (`popGraph()`) in `MainCtrl`:

```
function MainCtrl($scope, $http){
    callEndpoint();
    var data = {"xData": ["Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat","Sun"],"yData":[{
        "name": "Door",
        "data": [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, popGraph(), 21.5, 25.2]
    }, {
        "name": "Drawer",
        "data": [2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8]
    }, {
        "name": "Cupbaord 1",
        "data": [9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6]
    }, {
        "name": "Cupboard 2",
        "data": [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0]
    }]}        
    $scope.lineChartYData=data.yData
    $scope.lineChartXData=data.xData
}
```

Comment: did you try using `resolve`?

Comment: try promise: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: @Pradeepb could you assist with the syntax?

Comment: check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Wk7WD/486/) out. Let me know if it helps. I have used factory in which the `get` call is done. So before loading the controller, `get` call will be finished and data will be available for the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define your function in a main script, without using closures, your function is actually bound to the window object in JavaScript.
So inside your code you can always call:

```
console.log(window.callEndpoint);
```

and this will display in the console your function.
Again, this assuming that your script is inserted in the page and you don't have closures for changing scopes.

Then from angular routing you can easily use resolve block:

```
$routeProvider.when('/',{
        template: '<chart title="Bedroom Sensors" xData="lineChartXData" yData="lineChartYData" xName="Month" yName="Activations" subtitle="Sensor Usage"></chart>',
        controller:  'MainCtrl',
        resolve: {
           myData: function() {
             return window.callEndpoint().then(function(data) { return data; });
           }
        }

        })
```

Then inside your controller MainCtrl inject myData and you should have your data ready on init.

Change your function for getting data in this way:

```
function callEndpoint() {
    var sensorID = document.getElementById('sensorList').value;

 return 
 $.getJSON('http://193.61.148.125:443/SensorCentral/REST/SensorDataRangeNanos/19455746_3_10?startTs=0&endTs=9000000000000000000').then(function(data) {
    function(data) {
        return data;
     });
  })
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error stating `globalData is undefined` (I implemented your suggestion of adding a return and calling the function). `globalData` is declared at the top of my external `js` file.

Comment: I meant to add that I'm accessing `globalData` inside `MainCtrl` function, I'll add it to my original question.

Comment: I saw your edit and nope this won't work. I am editing my answer but please use resolve as I  showed you above

Comment: I am getting the following errors - `SyntaxError: function statement requires a name  scripts.js:19:12`
`ReferenceError: MainCtrl is not defined[Learn More]  root.js:4:9`

Comment: 19:12 refers to this line `function(data) {`

Comment: controller has to be the name you need to add apices. Updated

Comment: controller:  'MainCtrl',